# I am using Angular 4 for my project, writing code for range slider

Tags: angular, typescript

After compilation in browser I am getting this issue:

> moduleId should be a string in "Ng2SliderComponent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb6B4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zaBB.png)

While compiling I am getting below error:

> Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; directives:
>   typeof SlideAbleDirective[]; changeDetection...' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Component'. Object literal may only specify known
>   properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the relevant code

Comment: please post meaningful code

Comment: My app.module.ts is  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Ng2SliderComponent } from './Slider/ng2-slider.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Ng2SliderComponent,
    SlideAbleDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: Hi @ Pardeep,  If you have any sample code for simple range slider post here ,I will changes according to my requirements,it should work in angular  2 or angular 4 ,if it was in angular 4 more usefulll me ,

Comment: @pardeep jain,After compilation in browser i am getting this issue can any one help on this its urgent for me " moduleId should be a string in "Ng2SliderComponent". Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to an old angular version. Since a long time (`NgModule`) the `@Component` decorator no longer has the `directives` array. This has been moved to the `NgModule` declarations array. You should remove any directive you have in your `@Component`, and move it to your `NgModule`

Comment: Hi @pierre ,  Then its giving error like has no export member slidbledirectives .

Comment: can you have a look at above images i have shared what exact error  i am getting